# Is it grammatically correct? "You can choose which one to show to users either A or B."

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

A

> You can choose which one to show to users either A or B.

B

> You can choose which one to show to users whether A or B.

are these grammatically correct if they appear in a document?

if not, How should I write in a document?

Comment: _"You can choose to show either A or B to users"_ ...or... _"You can choose which one to show to users, either A or B"_ . If you want to use "whether", then: _"You can choose whether to show A or B to users"_.

Comment: いえいえ . . . . . .

Comment: Be careful, *whether* gives the sentence a completely different meaning.  From "choose which", the options are "show A" and "show B".  But from "choose whether", the options are "show" and "don't show".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option A is fine; it just needs some punctuation. I'd suggest a dash.

> You can choose which one to show users - either A or B.